# Setting imageview to horizontal scroll view

Tags: android, android-imageview, horizontalscrollview

Hi I have an url which gives me 2 image links. I have to download the image and set the image. I'm using horizontal scroll view and have reached till getting the image url and downloading the image using async task. can some one let me know how to set image to horizontal scroll view.

```
public void fetchImageUrl(){
    String url="http://apps.aspelec.com/cms/api/UploadImageAndChangeComplaintStatus?companyid=1&callrecordid=13";
    StringRequest request=new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            System.out.println(response);
            getJsonUrl(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("ErrorListner=",error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(request);

}
public void getJsonUrl(String response){
    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(response);
        ArrayList<String> imgurl=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<1;i++){
          String dummyurl=jArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("ImagePath");
            System.out.println("dummy url=="+dummyurl);
            imgurl.add(dummyurl);
            setView(imgurl);
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){

    }
}
public void setView(ArrayList<String> imgUrl){
    for(int j=0;j<imgUrl.size();j++){
        vi=(LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v=vi.inflate(R.layout.custome_serverdownloadedimageview,null,false);
        img=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.customserverdownlodedimg);
        new DownloadImage(img).execute(imgUrl.get(j));
        //Picasso.with(this).load(imgUrl.get(j)).resize(100,100).into(img);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/supervisor_complaint_details_cardview"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="left"
    android:paddingBottom="25dp"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="25dp"
    tools:context="com.six30labs.cms.activity.VerifyDetailSupervisor">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutComplaintNameSupervisor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!--LABEL FOR COMPLAINT NAME-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verifyComplaintLabelSupervisor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/complaint_name"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />


        <!--TEXT FIELD FOR COMPLAINT-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verifyComplaintFieldSupervisor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/verifyComplaintLabelSupervisor"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/verifyComplaintFieldSupervisor"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!--TICKET NUMBER-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutTicketNumberSupervisor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutComplaintNameSupervisor">
        <!--LABEL FOR TICKET NUMBER-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verifyLabelTicketNoSupervisor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:text="@string/ticket_number"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:typeface="serif" />
        <!--TEXT FIELD FOR TICKET NUMBER-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/verifyTicketNumberFieldSupervisor"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/verifyLabelTicketNoSupervisor"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/verifyTicketNumberFieldSupervisor"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />


    </RelativeLayout>

        <!--Assigned Date & Due Date-->
        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/layoutAssignedAndDueDateSupervisor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutTicketNumberSupervisor">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutAssignedDateSupervisor"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <!--LABEL FOR Assigned DATE-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/verifylabelAssignedDateSupervisor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:text="@string/assigned_date"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <!--TEXT FIELD FOR Assigned DATE-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/VerifyAssignedDateFieldSupervisor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/verifylabelAssignedDateSupervisor"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
                </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutDueDateSupervisor"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <!--Label for due date-->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/verifylabelDueDateSupervisor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="@string/due_date"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <!--Text field for due date-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/VerifyDueDateFieldSupervisor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/verifylabelDueDateSupervisor"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutAssignedAndDueDateSupervisor"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <!--Completed Date & Priority-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutCompletedDateAndPrioritySupervisor"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/layoutCompletedDateSupervisor"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <!--LABEL FOR Completed DATE-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/verifylabelCompletedDateSupervisor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/completed_date"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:typeface="serif" />

                <!--TEXT FIELD FOR completed DATE-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/VerifyCompletedDateFieldSupervisor"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/verifylabelCompletedDateSupervisor"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textStyle="normal"
                    android:typeface="serif" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/verifyPriorityImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:src="@mipmap/calendar"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutCompletedDateAndPrioritySupervisor"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutVerifyServerImageLabel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider1">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/serverImageLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/view_Image"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:typeface="serif"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/layoutVerifyServerImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutVerifyServerImageLabel">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/serverDownloadedImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Custom Imageview

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/customserverdownlodedimg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please see I have other things to display on xml file, In the end I will be displaying the images..
My Horizontal scroll view is at the bottom of the xml file..

Comment: you can add a horizontal RecyclerView in place of ScrollView which will not just work perfect but also would be much user friendly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I will try to use that I was just reading about it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void setView(ArrayList<String> imgUrl){

serverDownloadedImageView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.serverDownloadedImageView);
serverDownloadedImageView.removeAllViews();
    for(int j=0;j<imgUrl.size();j++){

     ImageView img = new ImageView(this);

        new DownloadImage(img).execute(imgUrl.get(j));
        //Picasso.with(this).load(imgUrl.get(j)).resize(100,100).into(img);
    serverDownloadedImageView.addView(img,j)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
 horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_grid);
        int[] images = new int[]{R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ....R.drawable.image10};
        LinearLayout sv = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.horizontal_container);
        for (int i=0 ; i<images.length; i++){
            ImageView iv = new ImageView (this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            iv.setPadding(4,0,0,0);
            iv.setImageResource(images[i]);
            iv.setLayoutParams(imageViewLayoutParams);
            sv.addView(iv);
        }
```

And your xml should look something like this

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="40">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```